Option to enable/disable a tab in superset dashboards
I wanted to know if there's an option to show/hide dashboard tabs while exporting the dashboards from superset
could notice if all charts related to that tab and that tab's id is removed from yml and
re-exported & imported it again this will work but this is a lengthy task and requires manual efforts, wanted some smarter solution
